# Concurrent update queries locking rows when `where` clause doesn't match

Tags: mysql, locking, concurrency

My application sends messages to Slack.  On very rare occasions we may need to retract the message going out.  These retractions are handled by queueing a job for each `messageId` that has been created thus far.

I noticed during our last retraction about a week ago that we saw about 2k:

`` try restarting transaction (SQL: update `message` set `deleted_at` = 2018-12-04 04:47:44 where (`slack_channel_id` = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and message_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx))" ``

It seems like the queue jobs (which are absolutely happening concurrently) are stepping on each other's toes.  My expectation is that this query would only put a lock on the individual row it needs (we have a compound unique index on `slack_server_id`, `slack_channel_id` and `message_id`), but it seems like more than one job is locking this record.

Why are these concurrent update queries locking rows that don't match the `where` clause?

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `slack_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slack_channel_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slack_message_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `premium` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `slack_message_slack_id_channel_id_message_id_unique` (`slack_id`,`slack_channel_id `,`message_id`),
  KEY `slack_message_message_id_foreign` (`message_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `slack_message_slack_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`slack_id`) REFERENCES `slacks` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `slack_message_message_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`) REFERENCES `messages` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Update**

I've added an `id` auto increment primary column and it did not resolve the transaction issues.

Comment: Please add a tag for your DBMS.

Comment: "Queued jobs"??  Multiple *nix processes?  Java Threads?  Multiple webservers getting multiple requests?  What?

Comment: Do you have a 'composite' `INDEX(slack_channel_id, message_id)` (in either order)?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, that's what I meant by compound.  It's a unique index on those columns.  "queued job" is a term used by the framework, at the end of the day that verbiage is intended to communicate the concurrency.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE message`; I think we need to change the `PRIMARY KEY` and/or some secondary keys.

Comment: @RickJames :facepalm: I'm realizing I don't actually have a primary key on this table.  I didn't think it needed one... but now I'm thinking that's probably the reason this isn't working.

Comment: _Problem_:  The query uses `slack_channel_id`, but the table does not have such a column.

Comment: @RickJames Fixed.  I had changed the column names so as to abstract further from the actual project this is associated with.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Have you added the index I suggested?

Comment: 8.0.3.  Yes I have `INDEX(slack_channel_id, message_id)` and the columns are there.

Comment: Please fix the `CREATE TABLE` to be consistent -- `discord_channel_id` shows up in an index, but not in the column list.  And I don't see the 2-col index.

Comment: Updated.  Use the `create table` statement as the source of truth for how the table is structured/indexed.  There isn't just a 2-column index, it's part of the 3 column unique index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lesson to learn about indexing.  `INDEX(a,b,c)` is *not* optimal for `WHERE a=1 AND c=2`.  This is because only the leftmost column(s) of an index will be used; there cannot be any skipping over columns (`b`, in this example).

Back to your question.

```
INDEX(slack_channel_id, message_id)
```

is needed, and

```
INDEX(`slack_id`,`slack_channel_id `,`message_id`)
```

is *not* useful at all.  `slack_id` is in the way.

```
KEY `slack_message_message_id_foreign` (`message_id`),
```

will be *partially* useful -- namely for narrowing the search down to those rows with the desired `message_id`.

A [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on building optimal indexes.